# Prove if the chord joining the points of tangency of two tangents to a parabola goes through the focus, the tangents are perpendicular

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

This is an exercise from Morris Kline's "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach":

> Prove that if the chord (Fig. 4-23) joining the points of tangency of two tangents to a parabola goes through the focus, the tangents are perpendicular to each other. *Suggestion:* Use the reflection property of the parabola.  [image: e]

The text does not explain the solution completely, so I would just like to verify that mine is correct.

Let $R$ be the intersection of the two tangent lines below $F$.

Let $P'$ be a point on the tangent line to the parabola at $P$ to the right of $P$, and $Q'$ be a point on the tangent line to the parabola at $Q$ to the left of $Q$.

Since $QD'$ and $PD$ are parallel, $\angle D'QF + \angle DPF = 180 ^{\circ}$. Due to the reflection property of the parabola, $\angle FPR = \angle DPP'$ and $\angle Q'QD' = \angle FQR$. Then
$$2 * \angle FQR + \angle D'QF = 180 ^{\circ}\text{ and } 2 * \angle FPR + \angle DPF = 180^{\circ}$$

It follows that
\begin{align}
2 * \angle FQR + \angle D'QF  + 2 * \angle FPR + \angle DPF  &= 360^{\circ} \\ 
2 * \angle FQR + 2 * \angle FPR &= 360^{\circ} - (\angle D'QF + \angle DPF) \\
2 * \angle FQR + 2 * \angle FPR &= 360^{\circ} - 180^{\circ} \\
\angle FQR +  \angle FPR &= 90
\end{align}

Since $\angle FQR$ and   $\angle FPR$ are two of the angles of $\triangle QPR$, the measure of $\angle QRP$ must be $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: You're answer is correct.

Comment: @SarGe thank you!